# Lubuntu keyboard shortcut for menu

Tags: shortcut-keys, lubuntu, lxde

I'm using Lubuntu on an older machine, and I'm having trouble finding information on keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a shortcut for opening the navigation menu? I expected that the windows key might work, but no luck.

More generally, is there a reference for existing LXDE shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to find a shortcut for opening the navigation menu, but a list of keyboard shortcuts is located [Here](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/masami256/20110824/1314115532)

<del>Here you can download software that allows you to create of modify keyboard shortcuts [Here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://lambda.host22.com/?page=keybinder)</del> (broken link)

Comment: Actually it looks like `Alt-Space` on that list accomplishes it, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Oops, I was mistaken, I'm not sure what `Alt-Space` does.

Comment: I don't know why to backed out :).  Alt+space opens up the applications menu, similar to clicking on the upper right corner of the open application`s window.  Plus the link for keybinder allows you to manipulate shortcuts as you need.  Thanks

Comment: I first accepted because I thought `Alt-Space` would open the navigation menu, and un-accepted when I found that it didn't. After re-reading my question, I guess your answer does satisfy the more general part of the question. I'll give it a few more days to see if any other answer show up, and accept yours if it turns out to be the best one.

Answer (score 9):

Alt+F1 or Ctl+Escape are the keybindings for opening the main menu. All keybindings (as well as many other settings) are contained in ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

Comment: True, they are available in lubuntu-rc.xml, but is there a way to generate a prettier list? Xfce 4.10 has this code for getting a list of keyboard shortcuts: `xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -l -v`. I would think such a list would be easier to go through before deciding to allocate a shortcut that may already have been assigned to something else.

Comment: If you want a GUI then try obkey as recommended by @Jon. It may not be supported anymore, but that is probably not necessary either. If it works, it works. More than likely it will continue working as long as Openbox handles keybindings in the same fashion. If it doesn't work, than you will only lose the few minutes it takes to figure that out.

Comment: By the way, @vasa1, did Alt+F1 or Ctl+Escape work for you?

Comment: Neither of those work for me. Several others don't as well. I'm not sure why. I don't want to conclude anything because I have all the Ubuntu flavors other than Kubuntu on my laptop and maybe my system is a little confused. I'm waiting for 12.10 to have just Lubuntu and will see then. your point about obkey makes sense.

Comment: Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Escape work perfectly now that I have pure Lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

You can install xdotool and create a keyboard shortcut that runs the command

```
xdotool click 3
```

...which will create a right-click event at the location of the mouse

...and create a global keyboard shortcut for it in your WM... here are some useful openbox references:

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Openbox#Create_custom_keyboard_shortcuts

https://code.google.com/p/obkey/

Comment: Development seems to have ended for `obkey` according to the code.google.com link.