# (Lubuntu) Play/pause key and volume keys not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, media-buttons

I am unable to get the forward and backward keys, volume keys working, nor the play pause keys. I am using lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Maybe this link helps:http://askubuntu.com/questions/461093/volume-buttons-not-working-in-14-04?rq=1

Comment: @muzaffarhabibullayev That didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to make shortcut to the play button?

Comment: How would I go about in doing so?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I couldn't find out if there is an inbuilt option for making shortcut in LXDE, you will have to edit shortcut manually. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140307/lubuntu-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162718

Comment: If you don't want to mess around with these tweaks install gnome environment via Software center.It is easier to create shortcuts there.

Comment: Sadly i am unable to find the gnome environment. And also the xbindkeys just crashes everytime I try to get it to find the key i am pressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Try another music player (for example, audacious, banshee,etc)
   (sudo apt-get install audaciuos or sudo apt-get install banshee)
2. Try another desktop environment (gnome, xfce)
   (sudo apt-get install gnome or sudo apt-get install xfce)
   Xfce would be a better option if your machine is rather weak (less than 4 gb RAM)

In XFCE  go to Settings Manager > Keyboard Preferences > Shortcuts.

Also your keyboard button may not not be supported yet. Then you will have to wait for updates.

Comment: 1. I tried out audacious, and it didnt solve the issue, and i have been using banshee already. 

2. As for trying out a new desktop environment, i ran xubuntu in a  virtualbox, and still my media and volume keys did not work.

I was able to get them to work in linux mint though, so I shall be using that instead.