# Adjusting Lubuntu keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys

I read in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181647/382864) there is a config file for all keyboard shortcuts in:

```
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

I'm able to find it but I'd like an easier way to create/read/update/disable my keyboard shortcuts.

For example, I'd like to disable the keyboard shortcut for `Alt-Space` because I want to use it as the [Albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert) hotkey.

Is there an out-of-the-box solution? If not, what about a package you can recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a GUI approach I can only hint at [Obkey](https://github.com/nsf/obkey). It seems to be abandoned, so it may not work. I haven't used it myself.

But if that doesn't work, fret not! I'll show you how to do it manually.

Lubuntu-rc is an XML file, it uses tags to define its structure. Each element has an opening and closing tag like this `<tag></tag>` or like this `<tag />`.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combo is normally assigned to a ShowMenu action. To reassign the key combo, navigate to `~/.config/openbox` and edit the `lubuntu-rc.xml` config file using your editor of choice.

Search for the following element:

```
<keybind key="A-space">
  <action name="ShowMenu">
    <menu>client-menu</menu>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Replace with:

```
  <keybind key="A-Space">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>
      /path/to/albert_bin/
      </command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Yu must change /path/to/albert_bin/ to whatever is appropiate.

Finally save your changes and reload Lubuntu/Openbox.

---

Another neat feature is openbox chrooting, which allow to create simple mnemonic application launchers like this:

```
<keybind key="W-a" chroot="true">
  <keybind key="Escape C-c BackSpace">
    <action name="BreakChroot"/>
  </keybind>

  (add your key bindings here)

</keybind>
```

Pressing <kbd>Windows/Meta</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> ("a" for applications), one gets into the chroot, then it would be possible to launch apps by pressing single keys, for example, <kbd>t</kbd> for terminal. You need to add suitable key bindings for terminal and other apps.

To exit the chroot, press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

---

Check [this](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) out for more info on OB bindings and chroots.