# What's the shortcut for screenshot on Lubuntu laptop keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I already tried both Shift+Ctrl+print and Shift+SupKey+print but nothing seems to happen.
Already visited here [Lubuntu keyboard shortcut for menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140307/lubuntu-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu) with no result.

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you using?

Comment: I guess it depends upon what hardware you are using as well.  On my Dell there is a key for print screen which works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your home directory?  When I hit print screen (in Lubuntu 17.10) I get no indication that anything happened, but when I look in my home dir, the desktop picture is there.)

Comment: yes printscreen takes a screenshot by default but does not provide any notification.

Comment: Shift+Sup K+Print K!
I found the shots in the home directory; it doesen't seem to work well, tough: taking shots with that fold opened I can see it only works once out of two/three...better than nothing, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

there may be a setting in LXDE but you could just bind any key to `scrot` in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` (or possibly `lxde-rc.xml` for lxde sessions)

from `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` look for `<keyboard>`

```
<!-- Keybindings for running applications -->
<keybind key="W-e">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>scrot</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```